# Как можно сверстать данную часть панели навигации? И это не хедер

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как "Блог" разместить на одном уровне с остальными кнопками меню. Заранее прошу прощения за нубский вопрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
html {
   font-size: 10px;
}
body {
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: 'Futura PT'; /* Гарнитура шрифта */
    src: url(../fonts/Futura PT.ttf); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
}
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
ul{
 display: flex;
}   
a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
header{
 height: 53px;
 background: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 200px;
}


.top-slide{
 background: #ffffff;
}
.menu-container{
 height: 57px;
 width: 1366px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: baseline;
}
.menu-container a{
  color: #686868;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 24px 40px 14px 40px;
}
/*стилизация кнопок верхнего меню*/
.menu-container a:hover{
 background: #eeeeee;
 /*padding: 25px 30px;*/
 height: 10px;
 width: 90px;
}
#menu-checkbox{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="top-slide">
   <div><h2>Блог</h2></div>
            <div class="menu-container">
   <input type="checkbox" id="menu-checkbox">
   <nav rove="navigation">
    <label for="menu-checkbox" class="toggle-button" 
     data-open="Menu" data-close="Close" onclick></label>
     <ul class="main-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Для бізнесу</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Для Юристів</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Підписатися на розсилку</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
  </section> 
 </main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

флексы

```css
* {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
nav {
  display:flex;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
nav .nav-title {
  color:#222;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav .navigation {
  list-style: none;
  display:flex;
  color: gray;
  flex-grow:1;
}
nav .navigation li {
    padding: 10px;
}
nav .navigation li.selectable:hover {
    box-shadow:0 -1px 0 0 #3AE2CE inset;
}
nav .navigation li.left {
    flex-grow:1;
    text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-title">Блог</div>
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li class="selectable">Для бизнеса</li>
    <li class="selectable">Для юристов</li>
    <li class="left">Подписатся на рассылку</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```css
.header-top {
   height:40px;
    background: #efefef;
    line-height:40px;
}
.header-nav {
    height: 40px;
    background: #ccc;
    line-height:40px;
}
.header-nav .name {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    display:block
}
.header-nav ul {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
}
.header-nav ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
    margin-right:20px;
    display:block;
}
.header-nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.header-nav ul li.active {
    border-bottom:2px solid blue;
}
.clr {
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-top">
    Header top
</div>
<div class="header-nav">
    <div class="name">Блог</div>
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Для бизнеса</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Для Юристов</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```